# Simplifying a Resizing Method

Tags: c++, algorithm, classes

I'm making a simple container class for fun and education, but my rebuilding/resizing method seems rather inefficient.  Is there an easier way to do this?

```
// If FromFront is true, cells should be added or
// subtracted from the front of the array rather than the back.
void Rebuild(std::size_t NewSize, bool FromFront = false)
{
    const std::size_t OldSize = Size;
    Size = NewSize; // Size is used in other methods.

    Datatype* TemporaryStorage = new Datatype[OldSize]; // Allocate space for the values to be preserved while a new main array is made.

    for (std::size_t Index = 0; Index < OldSize; Index++) TemporaryStorage[Index] = BasePointer[Index]; // Copy values over to the temporary array.

    delete[] BasePointer; // Delete the main array...
    BasePointer = new Datatype[NewSize]; // ...And rebuild it with the appropriate size.

    for (std::size_t Iteration = 0; (Iteration < OldSize) && (Iteration < NewSize); Iteration++)
    {
        std::size_t BasePointerIndex = Iteration;
        std::size_t TemporaryStorageIndex = Iteration;

        if (FromFront) // We need to take special measures to give the indices offsets.
        {
            if (NewSize > OldSize) BasePointerIndex += (NewSize - OldSize);
            else TemporaryStorageIndex += (OldSize - NewSize);
        }

        BasePointer[BasePointerIndex] = TemporaryStorage[TemporaryStorageIndex]; // Copy values from the temporary array to the new main array.
    }

    delete[] TemporaryStorage; // Finally, delete the temporary storage array.
}
```

Comment: I must be missing something...why are you even using a temporary array?

Comment: @Mark Probably because I'm stupid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
void Rebuild(std::size_t NewSize, bool FromFront = false)
{
    const std::size_t OldSize = Size;

    Datatype* NewStorage = new Datatype[NewSize];
```

Rather then creating a temporary array and copying the existing data into it, just create the new array and copy into that.

```
    int CopyLength = std::min(OldSize, NewSize);
```

We start by determining how many elements we will actually copy

```
    if( FromFront )
    {
        std::copy(BasePointer + OldSize - CopyLength, BasePointer + OldSize,
                  NewStorage + NewSize - CopyLength);
    }
    else
    {
        std::copy(BasePointer, BasePointer + CopyLength, NewStorage);
    }
```

I use std::copy to avoid having to write a copying for loop myself.

```
    delete[] BasePointer; // Delete the main array...
    BasePointer = NewStorage;
    Size = NewSize; // Size is used in other methods.
```

delete the current array and replace it with my new array

```
}
```

Comment: std::copy further can actually be extra smart and copy in a more efficient way if the data type supports it (something like memcpy for primitive types).